# How to select from table with check if exist on another table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table which `ALLUSER` and `BLACKLISTNUMBER`

```
select tel_number, telnumber_id, from alluser
```

How to not select if number is in Blacklist?

Comment: It would be great if you include the table structure of both tables

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant tags. C# has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE NOT IN :

```
   select tel_number, telnumber_id, from alluser
   where tel_number not in 
  ( select tel_number from BLACKLISTNUMBER where 
   tel_number  is not null  )
```

Comment: This will work, assuming `tel_number` is non nullable in `blacklistnumber` (in this problem it better be!)

Comment: CODe Edited . Thnks for suggestion @mathguy

Comment: Thank you it was helped me. 
What should I do if BLACKLISTNUMBER is on another database?

Comment: @user2801618 use cross server query.

Comment: However it's both on oracle?

Comment: I solved my problem with your help. Thank you Mr. Bhosale. I used to created a database link to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `not in` something like:

```
select tel_number, telnumber_id from alluser
where tel_number not in (select tel_number from blacklist);
```

Or may be `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select tel_number, telnumber_id from alluser t
where not exists (select tel_number from blacklist where tel_number = t.tel_number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to accomplish this. You can use a join as well...

```
select    a.tel_number,
          a.telnumber_id
from      alluser         a
left join blacklist       b     on  a.tel_number = b.tel_number
where     b.tel_number is null
```